# Why isn't requests fetching data correctly?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm new to the Python requests module and I'm trying to export game data from a user from the [Lichess.org API](https://lichess.org/api#operation/apiGamesUser) (a chess website).

Here is my code:

```
import requests

url = "https://www.lichess.org/api/games/user/mbellm"

r = requests.get(url, params={"max":2, "analysed":True, "clocks":True, "evals":True, "opening":True})
print(r.content.decode("utf-8"))
```

The output received below however is missing key components...

```
[Event "Rated Bullet game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/IqlbjkHX"]
[Date "2019.01.13"]
[Round "-"]
[White "mbellm"]
[Black "Ruediruempel"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2019.01.13"]
[UTCTime "22:45:48"]
[WhiteElo "1097"]
[BlackElo "1202"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-8"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+7"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "60+0"]
[ECO "C50"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nf6 3. Bc4 Nc6 4. d3 Bc5 5. Nc3 Nd4 6. O-O O-O 7. Nxd4 Bxd4 8. Nd5 Nxd5 9. Bxd5 c6 10. c3 cxd5 11. cxd4 dxe4 12. Qg4 exd3 13. dxe5 d6 14. Bd2 Bxg4 15. exd6 Qxd6 16. f3 Bf5 17. Rad1 h6 18. a3 Bh7 19. Bb4 Qd4+ 20. Kh1 Qxb2 21. Rxd3 Bxd3 22. Rc1 Qxc1+ 23. Be1 Qxe1# 0-1


[Event "Rated Classical game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/sgNWdvkn"]
[Date "2019.01.13"]
[Round "-"]
[White "Stalingrad_1"]
[Black "mbellm"]
[Result "1-0"]
[UTCDate "2019.01.13"]
[UTCTime "04:15:39"]
[WhiteElo "1656"]
[BlackElo "1732"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "+13"]
[BlackRatingDiff "-13"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "900+15"]
[ECO "D00"]
[Termination "Normal"]

1. d4 d5 2. e3 Nf6 3. c4 c6 4. Qb3 Nbd7 5. Nc3 Nb6 6. cxd5 Nfxd5 7. Nxd5 cxd5 8. Bb5+ Bd7 9. Nf3 e6 10. Bxd7+ Qxd7 11. Ne5 Qc7 12. Bd2 Bd6 13. Rc1 Qe7 14. Qb5+ Kf8 15. f4 Bxe5 16. dxe5 Nc4 17. Bb4 1-0
```

The output above is not providing the information I requested - specifically I set `"evals:True"` which according to the above documentation means that it ought to have computer analysis values attached to each move e.g.: `12. Bxf6 { [%eval 0.23] } a3 { [%eval -1.09] }`, however that is missing even though I filtered to only games where the analysis is available by setting `"analysed":True`.

Additionally it seems to be ignoring the parameters `"clocks":True` and `"opening":True`, in fact the only parameter seemingly being taken into account is `"max":2`, why might this be?

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The api appears to be case sensitive and is expecting the string `"true"` in the boolean parameters, all lowercase.

```
r = requests.get(url, params={"max": 2, "analysed": "true", "clocks": "true", "evals": "true", "opening": "true"})
```

Result excerpt:

```
(...)

1. e4 { [%eval 0.12] [%clk 0:15:00] } 1... c5 { [%eval 0.18] [%clk 0:15:00] } 2. Nf3 { [%eval 0.19] [%clk 0:15:13] } 2... Nc6 { [%eval 0.08] [%clk 0:15:13] } 3. Bc4 { [%eval -0.2] [%clk 0:15:26] } 3... e6 { [%e
val 0.0] [%clk 0:15:06] } 4. Nc3 { [%eval -0.21] [%clk 0:15:37] } 4... Nf6 { [%eval -0.23] [%clk 0:15:12] } 5. d3 { [%eval -0.2] [%clk 0:14:53] } 5... d5 { [%eval -0.09] [%clk 0:15:13] } 6. exd5 { [%eval -0.53]
 [%clk 0:14:25] } 6... exd5 { [%eval -0.43] [%clk 0:15:21] } 7. Bb3 { [%eval -0.54] [%clk 0:14:27] } 7... Be7 { [%eval -0.31] [%clk 0:15:06] } 8. O-O { [%eval -0.37] [%clk 0:14:27] } 8... O-O { [%eval -0.41] [%
clk 0:15:19] } 9. a3 { [%eval -0.57] [%clk 0:14:02] } 9... Be6 { [%eval -0.52] [%clk 0:15:18] } 10. Ng5 { [%eval -1.72] [%clk 0:13:51] } 10... Nd4 { [%eval -0.68] [%clk 0:14:51] } 11. Nxe6 { [%eval -0.71] [%clk
 0:13:42] } 11... Nxe6 { [%eval -0.28] [%clk 0:15:01] } 12. Qf3 { [%eval -0.99] [%clk 0:13:27] } 12... Nd4 { [%eval -0.82] [%clk 0:14:53] } 13. Qd1 { [%eval -0.91] [%clk 0:11:51] } 13... Nxb3 { [%eval -0.79] [%
clk 0:15:04] } 14. cxb3 { [%eval -1.09] [%clk 0:12:00] } 14... a6 { [%eval -0.1] [%clk 0:14:08] } 15. d4 { [%eval -0.12] [%clk 0:11:15] } 15... h6 { [%eval 0.0] [%clk 0:13:24] } 16. dxc5 { [%eval -0.43] [%clk 0
:11:03] } 16... Bxc5 { [%eval -0.36] [%clk 0:13:37] } 17. Na4 { [%eval -1.18] [%clk 0:09:25] } 17... Rc8 { [%eval 0.09] [%clk 0:13:20] } 18. Nxc5 { [%eval 0.0] [%clk 0:09:20] } 18... Rxc5 { [%eval 0.06] [%clk 0
:13:29] } 19. Be3 { [%eval 0.0] [%clk 0:09:29] } 19... Rc8 { [%eval 0.16] [%clk 0:12:49] } 20. Qd4 { [%eval 0.14] [%clk 0:09:17] } 20... b5 { [%eval 0.31] [%clk 0:12:01] } 21. Rac1 { [%eval 0.23] [%clk 0:08:36]
 } 21... Qd6 { [%eval 0.36] [%clk 0:11:33] } 22. Bf4 { [%eval 0.2] [%clk 0:08:09] } 22... Qe6 { [%eval 0.13] [%clk 0:10:58] } 23. Rfe1 { [%eval 0.0] [%clk 0:07:37] } 23... Rxc1 { [%eval 0.03] [%clk 0:11:06] } 2
4. Rxc1 { [%eval 0.09] [%clk 0:07:45] } 24... Rc8 { [%eval 0.08] [%clk 0:10:36] } 25. h3 { [%eval -6.7] [%clk 0:06:39] } 25... Rxc1+ { [%eval -6.58] [%clk 0:10:46] } 26. Bxc1 { [%eval -6.37] [%clk 0:06:52] } 26
... Qe1+ { [%eval -6.21] [%clk 0:10:57] } 0-1
```

When you provide the python boolean value `True` for these params as in your question, it is ultimately converted to an uppercased string representation, as can be seen in this debug-level log of `urllib3` when making the call:

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://lichess.org:443 "GET /api/games/user/mbellm?max=2&analysed=True&clocks=True&evals=True&opening=True HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```